# SQL indexes How to ensure insert of value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-indexes

If I have the following index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Contacts ON Contacts (User_ID) WHERE (IsDefault=1)
```

To make sure `IsDefault` is set.

How can I simultaneously ensure/require that `IsDefault` is always set?

Could you do something like this?

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Contacts ON Contacts (User_ID) WHERE (IsDefault>1)
```

Comment: Can you set the default value on Contacts row?

Comment: What do you mean by "`IsDefault'` is always set?  Samples of "allowed" data and "not allowed" data would clarify.

Comment: Ensuring that the values used for an insert or update statement are "correct" is a matter for the application and the people using it. The database engine cannot control that - it can only prevent "bad" data from being stored in the table. Here it seems that you want a filtered unique index to prevent multiple "default" rows per User_ID. Note that this does NOT require each user have a default - only that one default exists **at most**. You are confusing related but separate issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `IsDefault` column does not allow NULL and create a default constraint with the desired default value, which will be used when the column is not explicitly specified on INSERT statements.

Example DDL, guessing at the column data type and desired default value:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Contacts
    ALTER COLUMN IsDefault bit NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Contacts
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Contacts_IsDefault DEFAULT (1) FOR IsDefault;
```